# Why can't open link for .java tag?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, tag-links

When I click on [.java](/questions/tagged/.java) tag on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183552/how-to-resolve-the-following-error-occured-while-i-am-using-restful-web-service-i) it redirect to link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.java
but can not open it. Shows error: ***OOOPS!! The link is broken.***

One more thing moderators should merge [java](/questions/tagged/java) and [.java](/questions/tagged/.java) tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search this way :P

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.]java`

also same for

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net`

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.]net`

**Edit**: I've retagged another questions to [java](/questions/tagged/java) btw.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5702989/revisions

Comment: what about merging the tag cause it has same meaning as java tag?

Answer (score 1):

That's because it's tagged `.java` and not `java`. OP probably made a mistake when tagging the question. I've retagged it.

Comment: Yes I know but why System allows `.java` tag if it can not build a link with `.` in it. The user do not have that much reputation to create new tags that means this tag is an old one.

Comment: Only the tag page itself doesn't work. All the other pages work : [Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/.java/info), [Tag Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/68097), [Top Users](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/.java/topusers). Only 1 question with that tag exists. Users with high rep on that tag suggest a synonym or merge it, I suppose